# Parsed moment is not valid. Why?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using this code:

```
var m = moment('150218 10:20:00', 'YYMMDD HH:MM:SS');
m.isValid();
```

returns `false`. Further:

```
m.toDate();
```

returns a Date object `Thu Aug 18 2016 10:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` which confirms the date parsing seems to choke on something.

Why? I tried both in recent Chrome and Firefox browsers, and moment.js latest (2.9.0). The strings passed seem ok, I doubled-checked with the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/). So what am I missing then?

Comment: You're using MM for minutes. It should be mm. Try YYMMDD HH:mm:SS

Comment: Duh, hope you all heard the big "slap in the face" sound :-)  No wonder I had a bit of voodoo around that format string.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MM:SS` needs to be dropped to lowercase (`HH:mm:ss`). Here's the [string formatting section](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)  of their documentation.

Comment: Link to the momentjs documentation on this subject: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

From [momentjs documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) you should try this :

```
var m = moment('150218 10:20:00', 'YYMMDD HH:mm:ss');
```

- `HH` for 24 hour time
- `mm` for 0..59 minutes
- `ss` for 0..59 seconds